# Do something while shift and left click pressed or right click pressed

Tags: while-loop, autohotkey

I have this small Autohotkey script

```
LoopFunc()
{
    while (GetKeyState("shift") && GetKeyState("lbutton")) || GetKeyState("rbutton")
    {
        send, {4}
        sleep, 500
    }
}

~rbutton::LoopFunc()

~+lbutton::LoopFunc()
```

<kbd>RButton</kbd> works as intended but the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LButton</kbd> only loops twice.

Any idea why?

EDIT:

I added this to my `while` loop

```
n := GetKeyState("shift", "p")
m := GetKeyState("lbutton")
tooltip, %n% %m%
```

First tooltip is `1 1`, second tooltip is `0 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ["p" parameter](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) to get the actual **p**hysical state of the button and [use `&`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) for <kbd>LShift</kbd>+<kbd>LButton</kbd>:

```js
LoopFunc()
{
  while (GetKeyState("shift", "p") && GetKeyState("lbutton", "p")) || GetKeyState("rbutton")
  {
    send, {4}
    sleep, 500
  }
}

~rbutton::LoopFunc()

~lshift & lbutton::LoopFunc()
```